# rsync to import/export delta-transfer or incremental copy result

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

My scenario is to distribute several GB files from a staging server to tens of identical destination servers. Since rsync can do delta-transfer or incremental copy, I was wondering when rsync file to 1st dest server, can rsync export the delta-transfer result? And use import that result for rsync'ing to the rest of dest servers. In this case, staging server can save CPU time on re-calculating delta-transfer. Is this possible?

```
Number of files: 160
Number of files transferred: 49
Total file size: 2993222827 bytes = 2854 MB
Total transferred file size: 1847285024 bytes =1761 MB
Literal data: 69543644 bytes = 66 MB
Matched data: 1777741380 bytes = 1695 MB
File list size: 3088
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 1256178
Total bytes received: 70240527 = 67 MB

sent 1256178 bytes  received 70240527 bytes  182157.21 bytes/sec =
0.17 MB/s total size is 2993222827 speedup is 41.87
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. This is what rsync's batch mode is for. From the man page:

> Batch mode can be used to apply the
>   same set of updates to many identical
>   systems. Suppose one has a tree which
>   is replicated on a number of hosts.
>   Now suppose some changes have been
>   made to this source tree and those
>   changes need to be propagated to the
>   other hosts. In order to do this using
>   batch mode, rsync is run with the
>   write-batch option to apply the
>   changes made to the source tree to one
>   of the destination trees. The
>   write-batch option causes the rsync
>   client to store in a "batch file" all
>   the information needed to repeat this
>   operation against other, identical
>   destination trees.
>
> Generating the batch file once saves
>   having to perform the file status,
>   checksum, and data block generation
>   more than once when updating multiple
>   destination trees. Multicast transport
>   protocols can be used to transfer the
>   batch update files in parallel to many
>   hosts at once, instead of sending the
>   same data to every host individually.
>
> To apply the recorded changes to
>   another destination tree, run rsync
>   with the read-batch option, specifying
>   the name of the same batch file, and
>   the destination tree. Rsync updates
>   the destination tree using the
>   information stored in the batch file.

An example:

```
$ rsync --write-batch=foo -a host:/source/dir/ /adest/dir/
$ scp foo* remote:
$ ssh remote ./foo.sh /bdest/dir/
```